# URLSearchParams not parsing query string

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, urlsearchparams

Using `react-router-dom` version 5.

Some component, rendered when matching a `<Route />`:

```
...

const { search } = useLocation();
const params = new URLSearchParams(search);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(search); // "?paramOne=1&paramTwo=2"
    console.log(params); // {}
  }, []);

...
```

Why does `params` not show `{ paramOne: "1", paramTwo: "2" }`?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue as you describe here in a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/urlsearchparams-not-parsing-query-string-f2z0yb). Could you try forking my sandbox and adding more of your code to see if the issue is elsewhere. Share the link to your sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using URLSearchParams as you should. You are getting URLSearchParams object and if you want to get it as a string, you should log `params.toString()`

Check out these links:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a misunderstanding on my end, for some reason I thought the `entries()` method returned key/value pair of the params...

Note to self; read the web docs more closely next time!